# Enabling CLR Integration on SQL Server 2008-r2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, configuration, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlclr

Looking for Enabling CLR Integration I found this document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131048.aspx that said to use the following code for setting to 1 the "crl enabled" variable.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

I want know If a reboot of SQL Server is required? Or, more generaly, what are the steps to follow in order to Enable CRL Integration?

Comment: Hi there. I was wondering if you could please change which answer is accepted. Not because I provided the other answer, but because the currently accepted answer is incredibly wrong, misleading, spreading misinformation, and is easily proven to be wrong (as shown in my answer). Thanks :) P.S. the official documentation is also incorrect in that this is _not_ an advanced setting. That is also easy to prove and I will update my answer in a moment to show how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The accepted answer is incorrect. The `WITH OVERRIDE` option of `RECONFIGURE` has absolutely nothing to do with whether or not a restart of SQL Server is required. The MSDN documentation for [RECONFIGURE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176069.aspx) states that `WITH OVERRIDE`:

> Disables the configuration value checking (for values that are not valid or for nonrecommended values)...

The fact is, *no restart of the SQL Server service is required when enabling, or disabling, the "CLR Integration" option* in `sp_configure`. A simple test (run on SQL Server 2008 R2, but works the same across all versions that support SQLCLR) proves this:

```sql
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled'; -- show current value
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 0; RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled'; -- show current value
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled'; -- show current value
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1; RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled'; -- show current value
GO
```

Results:

Pay attention to the `run_value` field. It starts out as "1" since "CLR Integration" is already enabled on my system. But it switches with only calling `RECONFIGURE`.

```
name          minimum   maximum   config_value   run_value
clr enabled   0         1         1              1

clr enabled   0         1         0              0

clr enabled   0         1         0              0

clr enabled   0         1         1              1
```

Additionally, it should be stated with regards to the initial code shown in the Question, the statement for

```sql
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
```

is unnecessary since `clr enabled` is not an advanced option.

To prove the point about `clr enabled` not being an advanced option, and even showing another way to prove that this option does not require a reboot, just execute the following simple query:

```
SELECT [name], [value], [value_in_use], [is_dynamic], [is_advanced]
FROM   sys.configurations
WHERE  [configuration_id] = 1562;
/*
name           value    value_in_use    is_dynamic    is_advanced
clr enabled    1        1               1             0
*/
```

As you can see in the result set shown above, `is_advanced` is `0`, meaning "not an advanced option (yes, the official Microsoft documentation is currently incorrect; I will update it when I have time). Also, `is_dynamic` is `1`, meaning that simply executing `RECONFIGURE` will enable the option immediately, not requiring a restart of the instance.

**To summarize:** The sum total of all steps required to enable "CLR Integration", and without needing to restart the SQL Server service, are as follows:

```sql
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
```

That's it. <sup>**</sup>

---

<sup>**</sup> WOW64 servers *will* require a restart of the server in order for this option to take effect. ( [clr enabled Server Configuration Option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175193.aspx) )

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Definitely deserves an upvote!

Answer (score 8):

If you use `with override` option, then restart is not required.

```
EXEC sp_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options' , '1';
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

EXEC sp_CONFIGURE 'clr enabled' , '1'
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

Comment: This is absolutely incorrect. Not only in terms of what `WITH OVERRIDE` does, but also that anything is even needed in the first place. `RECONFIGURE` by itself already updates the enabled/disabled state with no need for restart.